# AssertJ - chaining together returns and extracting

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertj

Sometimes sonar cloud is complaining about number of assertions in tests. I wanted and found out how I can chain assertions one to another, but theres a case where I cannot figure out how I can chain assertions.

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.assertj.core.groups.Tuple;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class FakeTest
{
    @Test
    void fakeTest()
    {
        // given
        var resStatus = "FINISHED";

        var tc1 = "Test case 1";
        var r1 = "GOOD";

        var tc2 = "Test case 2";
        var r2 = "ALARMING";

        var res1 = Response.builder()
                .status(resStatus)
                .testCaseName(tc1)
                .result(r1)
                .build();
        var res2 = Response.builder()
                .status(resStatus)
                .testCaseName(tc2)
                .result(r2)
                .build();

        var result = Result.builder()
                .responses(List.of(res1, res2))
                .value("PASSED")
                .build();

        // then
        assertThat(result)
                .returns("PASSED", Result::getValue);

        assertThat(result.getResponses())
                .extracting("status", "testCaseName", "result")
                .contains(
                        Tuple.tuple(resStatus, tc1, r1),
                        Tuple.tuple(resStatus, tc1, r2));
    }
}

@Data
@Builder
class Result
{
    private String value;
    private List<Response> responses;
}

@Data
@Builder
class Response
{
    private String status;
    private String testCaseName;
    private String result;
    private String error;
}
```

How can I do assertions in FakeTest#fakeTest with chaining them instead of splitting to two assertions (one for assertThat(result).returns(...) and then assertThat(result.getResponses()).extracting(...)...)

What I want to achive is:

```java
assertThat(result)
                .returns("PASSED", Result::getValue)
                .extracting(Result::getResponses) // connection between two assertThat(...)
                .extracting("status", "testCaseName", "result")
                .contains(
                        Tuple.tuple(resStatus, tc1, r1),
                        Tuple.tuple(resStatus, tc1, r2));
```

I've found out that returning Assertion object are different:

- ListAssert<Response> when doing the chain of second assertion
- AbstractObjectAssert<capture of ?, List<Response>> when doing **merged** assertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extracting(singleParam or lambda)` can't return assertions specific to the extracted value type due to java generics limitations, in this case one can inform AssertJ of the type by using [asInstanceOf](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.html#asInstanceOf(org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory)) which would look like:

```java
static import org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactories.LIST;

assertThat(result)
                .returns("PASSED", Result::getValue)
                .extracting(Result::getResponses).asInstanceOf(LIST) // static import for readability
                .extracting("status", "testCaseName", "result")
                .contains(
                        Tuple.tuple(resStatus, tc1, r1),
                        Tuple.tuple(resStatus, tc1, r2));
```

[InstanceOfAssertFactories](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/InstanceOfAssertFactories.html) provides types AssertJ supports assertions for.

Another option would be to pass a lambda that extracts the responses and their fields directly (but that's probably of bit too much work).